# Modify URL based on search filter

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, web

I have a product search page. In which I have search field. After searching the list of product is displaying in result section. Now I want to modify the search using left side panel "Refine your search" , in this section there are some parameter that will narrow your search. 
Let user searching Shirt then my URL is http://localhost:8080/query?q=shirt
Now if user refine the result with color RED. I need to update the URL with
http://localhost:8080/query?q=shirt&color=red
How to do ?
I am using Spring MVC and JSP , Javascript is also an option.

Comment: I think you ned to give out a little bit more information.  Or at least some of the code that you have.  How is this left side panel set up?  Is it filled with radio buttons, checkboxes, input fields?  It is hard to answer your question well with what you have provided.

Comment: in javascript, if you already know the _url params_ (q, color, etc...), you can build the url and then redirect (`window.location = 'http://localhost:8080/query?q=shirt&color=red';`). Hope it helps

Comment: @JonBlack Left side panel has radio button that contains let 5 colors. If I am selecting one of them the URL should append the color attribute and refresh the result list.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't adverse to using jQuery, then you can implement this.  It doesn't completely account for the actual search query though since I don't fully know your implementation.

```
var currentColor = '';

$("input[type=radio]").on('click', function () {
    var previousColor = currentColor;
    currentColor = $(this).val();

    //if the parameter has already been set then replace, otherwise create a new one
    if (previousColor) {
        location.href = location.href.replace("color=" + previousColor, "color=" + currentColor);
    } else {
        location.href = location.href + '&color=' + currentColor;
    }
});
```